# How to run and get output from another application using C#

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

**Summary:**

I have a WinForm application doing some works and writing some output with `System.Console`, Here is the code:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Console.WriteLine("Some String");

    return 1;
}
```

Suppose we name it `SubApp.exe`

In another program, I want to execute this `subApp.exe` and read the output which it creates with `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SubApp.exe", "Some Parameter");
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
```

**Question:**

But unfortunately, both `output` and `error` is empty and even worse the `exitCode` is `0`. What is the problem? Am I doing the procedure in the right way?

Comment: Please paste your actual code and only omit what you feel is private info. It's hard to go off of massaged and untested code. For example you have `System.Diagnosis`. And just off the top of my head, double check you are actually pointing at the correct .exe (perhaps accidentally pointed at Debug instead of Release or vice-versa).

Comment: you code is wrone here `System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnosis.Process.Start("SubApp.exe", "Some Parameter");` you should use `System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SubApp.exe", "Some Parameter");`  you have used `Diagnosis`

Comment: and after fix your code is working fine

Comment: @TyCobb and @mostafizur, It's my mistake, I mean `Diagnostics`

Comment: ok isn't my present solution not working ?

Comment: and please excuse me, I must separate two sentences, I mean the sentence after Suppose we name it `SubApp.exe`

Comment: No, It's not working @MostafizurRahman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111563/discussion-between-mostafa8026-and-mostafizur-rahman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `SubApp` to write argument to the console then it will return the console output to the process output

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Console.WriteLine(args[0]); // this will print only 'Some' part of argument all string will be in args seperating by space
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]); // this will print "Parameter"

    return 1;
}
```

then call your `SubApp`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("SubApp.exe", "Some Parameter");
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();

int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
```

after executing this you will get `Some Parameter` into your `output` variable

Comment: I don't have any problem with Arguments, My problem is output of the process, It is empty always.

Comment: my present solution is ok I have tested it just now, make sure your other things are ok

Comment: Do you create a winform application or just console one?

Comment: I have create a console application as you have

Comment: Did you receive 1 as exitCode?

Comment: No I don't have console application, both of them are Windows Form Application

Comment: so why do you have used `Console.WriteLine` in youe question ?

Comment: To get some output that I need which create with SubApp.exe

Comment: it mean you are using console app so I have show your using console app, edit your question using winform app